# How to drag all nodes and connection together

Tags: jsplumb

I want to drag all nodes, connections together when i click and drag anywhere inside the instance. Though, when i drag any node, i don't want other nodes to be dragged. I could find `addToDragSelection()` to do this. But, how do i enable it only when i click and drag anywhere outside the nodes.

```
this.instance = newInstance({
      dragOptions: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        zIndex: 2000,
        containment: ContainmentType.notNegative
      },
      container: this.wrapper.nativeElement,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like the way everything pans in the Toolkit edition?

https://demo.jsplumbtoolkit.com/flowchart-builder/

There is no support for this in the Community edition. You'd have to write code yourself to do this.